# Получение имени файла из директории

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `/site.ru/public_html/nop_urd_1/nod1A88.nup`
Как описать регулярное выражение, чтобы получить `nod1A88.nup`
Моё выражение `"/[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+/";`
выдаёт `site.ru`.
Не улавливаю как задать отрицание, чтобы `site.ru` не выдавало, а получалось `nod1A88.nup`

Comment: Хм.

      #[^/]+$#

пойдёт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str="/site.ru/public_html/nop_urd_1/nod1A88.nup";
$mas=explode("/",$str);
echo $mas[sizeof($mas)-1];
```

А зачем регулярка?

ну блин ну почему все всегда хотят готового и не могут подумать.

Да sizeof($mas) - получим кол-во элементов, но в массивах, как очень хочется, чтобы все всегда помнили, отсчет начинается с **0** следовательно **sizeof($mas)-1**

Comment: Undefined offset: 5

Comment: sizeof - 1 всё же?

Comment: У меня не заработало. Для меня предпочтительнее регулярка. Есть предложения?

Comment: @northmule: почему предпочтительнее? Защитите своё предпочтение! Для простой задачи должно быть адекватно простое средство, разве не так?

Comment: я не совсем уловил с примером с sizeof, а в предыдущем возможно не так высказался, хотелось бы получить ответ именно с регуляркой? Другие решения тоже интересны.

Comment: @northmule: идея тут такая: разбить на куски по "/", и взять последний кусок. Номер последнего куска всё же, судя по всему, sizeof(...) - 1.

Comment: @northmule не работает потому что никто думать не хочет, хочет все всегда получить на халяву, быстро, правильно и т.д. и НИКТО, повторяю, НИКТО не хочет хотя бы немного пошевелить мозгами.

Comment: @Shrek: ну вот, я испортил вам учебную ловушку :( предупреждайте заранее! :)

Comment: "ну блин ну почему все всегда хотят готового и не могут подумать."
ТАк учусь только, познаю php по средствам книг, проб, ошибок и поиска ответа у других.

Answer (score 6):

Как вариант:

```
$path = "/site.ru/public_html/nop_urd_1/nod1A88.nup";
$result = basename($path);
```

Comment: Краткость сестра таланта, я тоже сначал подумал о разбивании в массив, почти как на питоне получилось

`a = "/site.ru/public_html/nop_urd_1/nod1A88.nup";
b = a.split('/')[-1]`

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к остальным (более эффективным!) решениям регулярка может быть, например, просто

```
/[\w\.]+$/
```

Но всё же воспользуйтесь одним из других решений, предварительно разобравшись, почему они лучше. Поверьте, это окупится.

Comment: Спасибо, это я для саморазвития спрашивал. Воспользовался вариантом с basename (всё работает).

Comment: @northmule: отлично! тогда вы так и пишите в вопросе, а то все думают, что вы решаете задачу неадекватными средствами.

Comment: @vladD, потери производительности на регулярных выражениях не серьезны в таких простых выражениях.  Наиболее эффективным по скорости будет нечто вроде:  

    /(?<=\/)[^\/]++\$/
И это должно быть несущественно дольше explode или basename на предварительно оптимизированном выражении.  
Зря Вы так плохо о регексах. Парсинг сложных данных регулярным выражением существенно может сократить объем кода и затраты по времени на реализацию парсера.  
Плюсом ко всему можно еще использовать PIRE- он правда сильно ограничен в возможностях, но способен быстро обрабатывать большие объемы текста.

Comment: @ReinRaus: хороший код должен быть прост в поддержке. Вот например, вы легко найдёте, что доллар экранировать на самом деле было не надо? Компилятор вам эту ошибку не найдёт. Поэтому я против использования чересчур [сложных регулярных выражений](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

Comment: @vladD, доллар экранировать надо. Я с эффективностью ошибся:  

    /.*\/([^\/]++)$/
Это выражение кстати быстрее basename, но медленнее explode в 10 раз на тексте размером 1 МБ и в два раза медленнее на тексте 100 байт.

Comment: @ReinRaus: почему надо экранировать? regextester.com с `(?<=\/)[^\/]++\$` ничего не отматчил, с `[^\/]++\$` тоже, `[^\/]++$` сработало. Скорее всего был бы аналог

    auto pos = s.find_last_of("/");
    return s.substring(s + 1);

(в переводе с C++)